# Как выполнить foreach в языке Dart (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

Данные ввел из json-а , все работает отлично , но сейчас выводиться только первый элемент.
Как мне написать здесь типо foreach-а чтобы все элементы с циклом вывелись на экран.
Строго не судите, я новичок.
Спасибо.

```js
class TreePage extends StatefulWidget {
  String vp;
  TreePage({this.vp});
  @override
  _TreePageState createState() => _TreePageState();
}


class _TreePageState extends State<TreePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text('Текст',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: new FutureBuilder(
        future: getPhoneFinal(widget.vp),
        //future: codePhone(widget.code),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          List data = snapshot.data;

          if(snapshot.hasError){
            print (snapshot.error);
            return Text('Не удалось получить ответ от сервера',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,
            fontSize: 22.0)
            );
          }
          else if(snapshot.hasData ){
            
            return new Container(              
                   child:Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      
                      new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),  

                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                           'Тип штрафа:  ${data[0]['VDescription']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                           'Адрес:  ${data[0]['VLocation']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                           'Дата:  ${data[0]['VTime']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
               
            );
                       
          }else if(!snapshot.hasData){
            return new Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }
        }),
    );
  }

  getFine(String vp) {}
}

Future<List> getPhoneFinal(String numbCar) async{
  String url = 'http://xxx/xxx?xxx=$numbCar';
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  return json.decode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 вариант (Его следует использовать для маленьких списков):**

```
class _TreePageState extends State<TreePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text('Текст',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: new FutureBuilder(
        future: getPhoneFinal(widget.vp),
        //future: codePhone(widget.code),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasError){
            print (snapshot.error);
            return Text('Не удалось получить ответ от сервера',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,
            fontSize: 22.0)
            );
          }
          else if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.isNotEmpty){
            List data = snapshot.data;
            for(int i =0; i< data.length; i++) { 
              return new Container(
                   child:Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),  

                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                           'Тип штрафа:  ${data[0]['VDescription']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                           'Адрес:  ${data[0]['VLocation']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                           'Дата:  ${data[0]['VTime']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )

            );
            }
          } else{
            return new Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }
        }),
    );
  }

  getFine(String vp) {}
}
```

**2 вариант (Его следует использовать для больших списков):**

```
class _TreePageState extends State<TreePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text('Текст',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: new FutureBuilder(
        future: getPhoneFinal(widget.vp),
        //future: codePhone(widget.code),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
          if(snapshot.hasError){
            print (snapshot.error);
            return Text('Не удалось получить ответ от сервера',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,
            fontSize: 22.0)
            );
          }
          else if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.isNotEmpty){
            List data = snapshot.data;
            return new Container(              
                   child: ListView.builder(                                                  
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

              return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[

                      new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),  

                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                           'Тип штрафа:  ${data[0]['VDescription']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                           'Адрес:  ${data[0]['VLocation']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                      new Container(                                                
                          child: new Text(                           
                           'Дата:  ${data[0]['VTime']}'                         
                            ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );},),

            );

          }else{
            return new Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }
        }),
    );
  }

  getFine(String vp) {}
}
```